# Pagination with alethes:pages using a subscription

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, pagination

folks.  I'm using `alethes:pages` for pagination in my Meteor app, and I'm needing to use an existing subscription to control the data it's displaying.   It seems that the way it works is that it just paginates ALL of the records in a collection, and not the specific stuff I want shown.

The code I've got so far looks like this, defining the pagination:

```
BrowsePages = new Meteor.Pagination(Mods, {
    perPage: 15,
    sort: {
        createdAt: -1
    },
    templateName: "browseModsList",
    itemTemplate: "browseModItem",
    table: {
        fields: ["name", "category", "createdAt"],
        header: ["Name", "Author", "Category", "Date Added", "Rating", "Current Version"],
        class: "table table-striped"
    },
    divWrapper: false,
    auth: function(skip, sub) {
        var theCat = Categories.findOne({slug: Router.current().params.slug});
        return Mods.find({category: theCat._id});
    }
});
```

I was assuming that it would limit the paginated data to the cursor that I'm returning via `auth`, but it's just hanging there with a spinner now.

I'm pretty confused, anyone who could shed some light on this would be awesome.  I'm looking to enforce that same limitation (somehow) onto the pagination, I just don't know how to do it.

Here's more relevant code:

**Route:**

```
// Browse
Router.route('/browse/:slug', function() {
    this.render('browseModsList');
}, {
    name: 'browse',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Subs.subscribe('catMods', this.params.slug)
        ]
    }
});
```

**Publication**

```
Meteor.publish('catMods', function(tag) {
    var category = Categories.findOne({slug: tag});
    if (category) {
        var catId = category._id;
        return Mods.find({category: catId});
    } else {
        return this.ready();
    }
});
```

Thanks ahead of time for any assistance, as usual!

Answer (score 0):

Add the fields key as shown below.

```
BrowsePages = new Meteor.Pagination(Mods, {

    perPage: 15,
    fields: {name: 1, category:1, createdAt:1},

});
```